# Torsion of quotient module $\mathbb{Z^2}/L$ over $\mathbb{Z}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

How can I find the torsion of the module $\mathbb{Z^2}/M$ over $\mathbb{Z}$, where $M$ is the subgroup of $\mathbb{Z^2}$ generated by the vector (4,6)?

Through this question, i want to get a concrete example of the notion of torsion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Hint:* You're looking for all $(x,y) \in \mathbb Z^2$ such that $n(x,y) \in M$, that is $n(x,y)=m(4,6)$, for some $m,n \in \mathbb Z$.